# Image/file storing in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, file-upload, mean-stack

I am trying to store image/file using gridfs but i am having some difficulties.How do i store an image/file in mongo DB using GridFS/any. I am using express and node as my middle ware and angular as front end.

Comment: Here are some useful information on when to use gridfs : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#when-to-use-gridfs. You can store images using gridfs though it's not the best use you can make of it. As for your question, can you give us more information about the problems you're facing ?

Comment: This question seems better fitted for a quick web search ("how do I use this feature?").